# using .join() for a group of threads gives rise to an unexpected result

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to execute a group of threads at the same time and wait for them to finish before resuming the main thread. This is my custom class MyRunnable:

```
 Class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
       int value;
       MyRunnable(int value){
          this.value = value;
       }
       @Override
       public void run(){
          System.out.println("Started thread " + value);
          System.out.println("Finished thread " + value);
       }
    }
    Thread[] myThreads;
    int total = 25;
    int size = 5;

    while(total > 0){
       total -= 5;
       size = 5;
       myThreads = new Thread[size];

       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
          myThreads[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable (i));
       }
       for(Thread t:myThreads){
          T.start()j
       }
       for(Thread t:myThreads){
          try{
             t.join();
          } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
             System.out.println("error");
          }
       }
       System.out.println("set finished");
    }
```

I need a group of five threads to execute at a time and the main thread to continue only when all threads have finished execution. The code above does not work as calls to .join seem to be ignored. I also tried giving each of the threads in a group a random sleep time to see if the unexpected result is due to the threads finishing faster than the call to .join() could be made. The result was still the same.

Comment: What's preventing you from using an `Executor` here?

Comment: The line of code that actually starts the thread has two typos in it, so I suspect this is not your actual code, and your real version has so e bug we don't know about in it.

Comment: I like the "`Class`" definition... copypasted from MS Word?

Comment: `for(Thread t:myThreads){T.start()j}` -> `for(Thread t:myThreads){t.start();}`

Comment: I did corrections to code. It was missing a main method.

Comment: Regarding your code. I suspect that the threads are all finished by the time the code finishes running. I would suggest added Thread.sleep to delay each thread.

Comment: Sorry for the poor format. I used a mobile phone to write the code. @dARKpRINCE: what do u mean by "...time the code finishes running". there is no way the main thread can skip making a call to .join() for each thread is there?

Comment: That's for sure. That command will not be skipped. You might have some error which prevents the thread from creating in first place.

Comment: @dARKpRINCE: but the result I am getting does not show it. What is supposed happen is 5 threads running at a time. All of them must finish before the string "set finished" is printed. but that is not what happens. Can u try executing the code? Just copy the code into a main method and correct the error on line "T.start()j" to "t.start()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked (to add a println after each `join` call), compiled and ran your application, and I see NO evidence that `join` is being skipped.  The code and output are below.

Code:

```
package test;

public class ThreadTest {

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        int value;

        MyRunnable(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Started thread " + value);
            System.out.println("Finished thread " + value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread[] myThreads;
        int total = 25;
        int size = 5;

        while (total > 0) {
            total -= 5;
            size = 5;
            myThreads = new Thread[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                myThreads[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable(i));
            }
            for (Thread t : myThreads) {
                t.start();
            }
            for (Thread t : myThreads) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                    System.out.println("joined");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("set finished");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Started thread 0
Finished thread 0
Started thread 2
Started thread 1
Finished thread 1
Finished thread 2
Started thread 3
Finished thread 3
joined
joined
joined
joined
Started thread 4
Finished thread 4
joined
set finished
Started thread 0
Started thread 1
Started thread 2
Finished thread 2
Started thread 3
Finished thread 0
Finished thread 3
Finished thread 1
joined
joined
joined
joined
Started thread 4
Finished thread 4
joined
set finished
Started thread 0
Finished thread 0
Started thread 1
Started thread 2
Finished thread 1
Finished thread 2
joined
Started thread 4
Finished thread 4
Started thread 3
joined
joined
Finished thread 3
joined
joined
set finished
Started thread 0
Started thread 3
Finished thread 3
Started thread 4
Started thread 1
Started thread 2
Finished thread 1
Finished thread 4
Finished thread 0
Finished thread 2
joined
joined
joined
joined
joined
set finished
Started thread 0
Started thread 1
Finished thread 0
Finished thread 1
Started thread 2
Finished thread 2
Started thread 4
joined
joined
joined
Started thread 3
Finished thread 4
Finished thread 3
joined
joined
set finished
```

Comment: I also dont see the issue. :)

Comment: I found the problem. I mistakenly used System.err instead of System.out to print the "set finished"  string. In my case the result looked as if the .join was being ignored. Thank you for your help.